# Server side response to allow client side routing

Tags: node.js, http, single-page-application

I am developing a single page application that has a client side router.  so although the base url to run the application will be either http:://example.com or http:://example.com/index.html - skipping the domain name that is routes '/' and '/index.html'

But somewhere in my application, because of my client side router, I may call up a route something like '/appointments/20160113 and the client router will redirect me to the appropriate "Appointments Page" inside my SPA passing the parameter of todays date.

But if the user calls directly http://example.com/appointments/20160113, I am led to believe that the server should respond directly with /index.html so the browser doesn't get a 404.

I am building the server using nodejs (specifically the http2 module, but I don't think that is very important, and my examples don't use https, although with http2 they do).  I just tried changing the server so if its hit with an unknown url it responds with the index.html file.

**However**, the browser sees this as its first response and then makes requests for the rest of its attached files relative to the url (so for instance follows up with /appointments/20160113/styles/main.css).  This leads to an infinite loop, as the server responds with another copy in index.html (and immediately gets a request back for /appointments/20160113/styles/styles/main.css ).

Its too early in the lifecycle of the page for the javascript to be running yet (and specifically the router software), so clearly the approach is too simplistic.

I have also written the client side router (using the history api) so I can change things if I need to.

How **should** this situation be handled.  I am thinking perhaps a 301 redirect to /index.html or something and then the router's initial dispatch knows this and can do a popstate or something. I ideally want to support the passing of urls via external means between users, but until I actually tried to implement it I hadn't realise the implications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is the best way or not, but having not received any answers on here, I decided to try a number of different ways and see which worked out the best.

Each way involved doing a 301 redirect to /index.html, and then providing the url from which I was redirecting via different mechanisms

This is what I tried

1. Setting a cookie with a short expiry date the value of which was the url
2. Adding a query string with a ?redirect= parameter with the url
3. Adding a #fragment after /index.html with the url

In the end I rejected 1) because chrome wasn't deleting the cookie after I had used it and making the value shorted lived depends on accurate timing between client and server.  The solution appeared too fragile.

I tried 2) and it was looking good until I came to test it.  Unfortunately setting window.location.search causes a page reload, and I was really struggling with finding out what was happening.  However, what I discovered in 3) about mocking could well be provided to a solution based on 2) so it is one that could be used.  I still might return to this solution as it "feels" right to me.

I tried 3) and it worked quite well.  However I was struggling with timing issues in testing since my router element was using the #fragment during initialisation, but I couldn't set the window.location.hash until after the router was established in the test suite.  I wanted to mock window.location.hash with sinon so I could control it, but it turns out you can't

The solution to this was for the router to wrap its own calls to window.location.hash in a library, so that I could mock the library.  And that is what I did in the end and it all worked.

I could go back to using a query string and wrapping window.location.search in a library call, so I could stub that call and avoid the problems of page reloading.